# Using scipy.optimize.curve_fit I can't fit V*cos(ω*t) function correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I have created the data from a function in python, so i was thought that the fit needed to be perfect, but it is not i don't know why

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 

def fun(offset, V, f, phi):
        return V * np.cos(2*np.pi*f * x + phi) + offset

    xData = np.arange(0, 1, 0.005) #time
    f = 2 #frequency
    yData = 5 * np.cos(2*np.pi*f * x)

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(fun, xData, yData, p0=[1, 1, 1])

    print(popt)

    plt.scatter(xData, yData, label="data")
    plt.plot(xData, fun(x, *popt), label="fit")
    plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
    plt.show()
```

[plotted data and fit points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhDJg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple problems, including your function definition and initial guess. This works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 

def fun(xData, offset, V, f, phi):
        return V * np.cos(2*np.pi*f * xData + phi) + offset

xData = np.arange(0, 1, 0.005) #time
f = 2 #frequency
yData = 5 * np.cos(2*np.pi*f * xData)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fun, xData, yData, p0=[0, 6, 2, 1])

print(popt)

plt.scatter(xData, yData, label="data", c='k')
plt.plot(xData, fun(xData, *popt), label="fit", c='r')
plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks, can you tell me if there is a way to find the right p0 values ?
Because I can't put the frequency in the values of p0, if that's what I have to find

Comment: `p0` is your guess for each parameter. Since you already know the frequency, amplitude, offset, and phase shift just by looking at the graph of the data, you can choose a `p0` guess which is similar to those values. If you don't know those values beforehand, you usually need to make an educated guess and/or try different configurations.